# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('something')"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to make a register page for my application and when I press submit button this error appears: 
`Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('firstName')"`

From what I understand, Thymleaf uses POJO's getters for validation and this means that firstName attribute couldn't be found. For registration I use a DTO for user entity, a DTO only for registration. If i use user entity this error never appears. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/registration.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form autocomplete="on" action="register.html" th:action="@{/user/register}"
                  th:object="${user}" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
                  role="form">
                <h2>Registration Form</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}"
                               class="validation-message"></label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="Name"
                               class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}"
                               class="validation-message"></label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
                               placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"
                               class="validation-message"></label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{username}"
                               placeholder="Username" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{emailAddress}" placeholder="Email"
                               class="form-control"/> <label
                            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('emailAddress')}" th:errors="*{emailAddress}"
                            class="validation-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phoneNumber')}" th:errors="*{phoneNumber}"
                               class="validation-message"></label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{phoneNumber}"
                               placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"
                               placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/> <label
                            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"
                            class="validation-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" th:field="*{confirmPassword}"
                               placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control"/> <label
                            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}" th:errors="*{confirmPassword}"
                            class="validation-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register User</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h2><span class="text-success" th:utext="${successMessage}"></span></h2>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

RegisterUserDto

```
@PasswordMatches
public class RegisterUserDto {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "This field can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "This field can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message = "This field can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "This field can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
    @ValidEmail
    private String emailAddress;

    @NotNull(message = "This field can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "This field can't be empty")
    @ValidPhoneNumber
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ValidPassword
    private String password;

    private String confirmPassword;

    //getters and setters
```

Controller

```
 @GetMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView registration(){

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        RegisterUserDto user = new RegisterUserDto();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid RegisterUserDto user,
                                      BindingResult bindingResult) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmailAddress());

        if (userExists != null) {
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("emailAddress", "error.user",
                            "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");

        } else {
            userService.createUser(user);

            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");

        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username",
            unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email_address",
            unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "notification_type",
    insertable = false)
    private String notificationType = "email";

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "is_active",
    insertable = false)
    private Boolean active = false;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserGroup> groups;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            mappedBy = "userId",
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private VerificationToken verificationToken;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Group> createdGroups = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters and setters
```

Comment: could you share user entity as well?

Comment: I updated the post and added user entity

Comment: did you try @Valid @ModelAttribute(value="user") in your     @PostMapping("/register") controller to bind the object?

Comment: Two things I noticed. I don't see th:object on your form. you have user/register on your form but I don't see controller mapped to this url.

Comment: @afaq That worked, but i don’t know exactly why. Thank you.
want2learn There is a th:object on the form. The entire controller class is mapped to “/user”. I forgot to add that, sorry.

Comment: @Robert that worked, cause your controller was expecting an object but it didn't know what object you were submitting, once you mentioned the exact name of the model attribute that you injected in your get mapping your post controller upon submission knew you were sending an object named "user", btw if that worked, you could up-vote the comment, if this satisfies you, I could make it the answer